# Finding conditions on functions for absolute continuity of measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ and $\lambda$ be finite measures of $[0,1]$ which are absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure: $\lambda << m$ and $\mu << m$

$$\lambda(A) = \int_Af(x)dx$$

$$\mu(A) = \int_Ag(x)dx$$

Find conditions on $f$ and $g$ so that $\lambda << \mu$.

My attempted solution is simply stating that $f$ and $g$ should be in $L^1$.

Comment: You want $\lambda \ll \mu$ which means that whenever $\mu(A)=0$ you have $\lambda(A)=0$. Since $f,g \geq 0$ (why?) this means that $f$ must sometimes be zero...when is that?

Comment: If $\mu(A) = 0$, it implies the$\int_A g(x)dm(x) = 0$ which means either $g = 0$ a.e. on $A$ or $m(A) = 0$. In that case $f$ has to be $0$ a.e on $A$, right? Or $m(A) = 0$

Comment: Yes: if $g=0$ Lebesgue-a.e. on a set of positive Lebesgue measure then $f=0$ Lebesgue-a.e. there too.

Comment: I see. I guess I was overthinking this. Can you look at this one too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1758616/given-lambda-mu-finite-measures-show-that-for-any-bounded-function-g-a