# Question on bounded function and Radon Nikodym Derivative.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given  $\lambda << \mu$ finite measures, show that for any bounded function $g$ and $A \subset [0,1]$ $$\int_A gd\lambda = \int_A ghd\mu$$ where $h$ is the Radon-Nikodyn derivative $$\frac{d\lambda}{d\mu}=h$$

If anyone can provide just a hint, it would be great. I am stumped by these questions on derivatives. Any resource would be helpful too. I'm finding Stein Shakarchi too difficult to understand.

My attempt: Consider $g^+,g^-$ separately and assume $\lambda \ge 0$. And then assume $g$ is a characteristic function $\chi_E$ and then assume the relationship holds for simple functions and then for non-negative measurable non-negative functions (by approximating with simple functions) and then for general functions by linearity.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need $g$ to be measurable? Otherwise, in your approach, how will you approximate it by simple functions?

Comment: Yes. g is measurable. But is the approach correct?

Comment: Sounds correct; $\lambda(E)=\int_E h d\mu$ is directly from the Radon-Nikodym theorem so you do not have to assume it. Probably worth your while to fill in the details if you're unsure.